# After a cancelled rebase in progress, I cannot update my branch from master branch?

Tags: git, github, git-rebase

I have a separate branch with many additions on my local and I used to rebase with master branch to keep up with the core development. Last time, since it took too long I cancelled the rebase as it was progressing. After that point, whenever I ask for rebase, git says "Already up-to-date" but I am sure that it is not. In that case, how should I diagnoise the problem and solve it without damaging my local copy?

Comment: What do you mean by "cancelled", and what does `git status` say about your repository's current status?

Comment: Since you have cancelled the rebase operation, .git/rebase-merge/* will be active. So, it won't allow you to update the repo. Best practice is you should run either, "git  rebase --continue" to continue the rebase or "git rebase --abort" before you update your code. If you are happy with my comment, i can post my answer about the same.

Comment: @love if your comment is an answer, you should post it as answer

Comment: @TimCastelijns I have posted my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Once some rebase starts in git repo, it creates `.git/rebase-merge/*` folder and it will be present till rebase operation is completed.

In your case, if cancel the rebase operation, it will not remove any `.git/rebase-merge/` folder automatically, which means that process is still active.

So, its always better to choose either below options:

- > **git rebase --abort**
  >
  > {To abort the rebase operation (the perfect way to cancel the operation)
- > **git rebase --continue**
  >
  > {To finish the rebase operation}

Comment: it does not work. There is no active rebase operation. The problem is still the main branch is updated but when I try to merge with my branch it says "already up-to-date"